# How can I find the MAC address of a specific device via Windows batch file?

Tags: macos, batch-file, mac-address

I'm trying to write a script that will compare the MAC address of Local Area Connection to the MAC address in software licenses to see if one of the licenses matches the machines.  The part that has me stuck right now is pulling the MAC address of a specific device "Local Area Connection".

I have tried using search features such as:

```
ipconfig /all | findstr^ /C:"Local Area Connection"^ /C:"Physical Address" > C:\temp\macaddress.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%i in (C:\temp\macaddress.txt) do @echo The MAC Address of %%i is %%j
pause
```

I really don't need the echo in the above attempt, but I use it for debugging.

But still the above statement puts text into a file like this:

"Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-37-10-D1-98-2C

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5D-26-0A-11-11-15"
(quotes added by me to show the beginning and end of text file)

From that, I'm not sure how to pull the MAC address that comes after Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection, especially when they're not on the same line.

I need to do this with a batch file in Windows XP Professional.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This old script should work.
It searches first for the correct adapter, and then it waits until a line containing the string "Physical".
The :Normalize function is for removing **< Carriage Return>** in the output of ipconfig at XP systems, as microsoft doesn't know exactly that a line should end with CR/LF not with LF/CR.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

rem call :GetIP ip_WLAN "Drahtlos"
rem echo ---
set OS_Version=XP
call :GetIP result  "Ethernet adapter" "Physical"

echo mac=%result%

goto :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:GetIP <resultVar> <AdapterName>
:: resultVar    return variable for the searched value
:: AdapterName  part of the adapter name
setlocal
set /a found=0
if "%OS_Version%"=="Win7" set ipText=IPv4
if "%OS_Version%"=="Vista" set ipText=IPv4
if "%OS_Version%"=="XP" set ipText=IP-
if "%~3"=="" (
    set searchText=!ipText!
) ELSE (
    set "searchText=%~3"
)
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a IN ('ipconfig /all') DO (  
  call :Normalize first "%%a.dummy"
  call :Normalize post "%%b.dummy"

  if "!post!"=="_" (
    if "!first:%~2=!" NEQ "!first!" (
        set /a found=1
        rem echo adapter found "!first!"
    ) ELSE (
        if "!first!" NEQ "_" (
            set /a found=0
            rem echo - !first! !post!
        )
    )
  )

  if !found! EQU 1 (
    rem echo try "!first!"
    if "!first:%searchText%=!" NEQ "!first!" (
        set ipAddr=!post:_=!
        set ipAddr=!ipAddr: =!
        rem echo IP found !post! for adapter
    )
  )
)

(
  endlocal
  set %~1=%ipAddr%
  goto :eof
)

:Normalize
set %~1=_%~n2
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks, @jeb!  I had to change the comment indicators from "rem" to "REM !#".  Other than that, it looks like it works great!  Thank you so much!  I had spent a few days on this on my own but without much success.  Thanks again!